# Compare one element from multiple 2D arrays (java)

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, compare

I have multiple 2D arrays of Strings that are layed out a little like this

```
Array 1
 [0] = ["01/01/01","Bill","17","0.86"]
 [1] = ["02/01/01","Bill","12","0.84"]
 [2] = ["03/01/01","Bill","15","0.85"]
Array 2
 [0] = ["01/01/01","Joe","14","0.81"]
 [1] = ["02/01/01","Joe","15","0.83"]
 [2] = ["04/01/01","Joe","19","0.85"]
```

I'm trying to compare only data from the same days, so what I need to do is search both arrays for dates that are in one but not the other and then remove them. So in the above example I would remove [2] from both of the arrays. Is there a way of doing this using List/Collection retainAll or will I have to write a loop? Oh I'm using Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of removing items using collection. But if both the arrays are sorted by date, you would be able to compare the data without removing the missing dates from each of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't prefer using arrays for this problem. Removing elements from array is a bad idea. You might try linked list. Something like this

```
for (int i=0; i < array1List.size(); i++) {
    String date = array1List.get(i)[0];
    int index = -1;
    for(int j=0; j < array2List.size(); j++) {
        if array2List.get(j)[0].equals(date)) {
            index = j;
            break;
        }

        if(index >= 0) array2List.remove(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has a bug in it @Pat.  If you are removing from `array2List` as you are walking across it then `j++` will cause you to skip over an item.  I think your `if(index >= 0)` test should have an `else j++` and remove the increment from the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

To use a `Collection` to do this you will have to put each array entry into an object.  Something like:

```
class DayInfo {
    String date;
    String name;
    ...
    public DayInfo(String[] arrayData) {
        this.date = arrayData[0];
        this.name = arrayData[1];
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof DayInfo))
            return false;
        if (date == null) {
            return ((DayInfo)obj).date == null;
        } else {
            return date.equals((DayInfo)obj).date);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (date == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return date.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Then if you load both of your arrays into `DateInfo` collections:

```
Set<DayInfo> dayInfos1 = new HashSet<DayInfo>(array1.length);
for (String[] arrayEntry : array1)
    dayInfos1.add(new DayInfo(arrayEntry));
Set<DayInfo> dayInfos2 = new HashSet<DayInfo>(array2.length);
for (String[] arrayEntry : array2)
    dayInfos2.add(new DayInfo(arrayEntry));
```

Now you can use the `retainAll` in both directions:

```
// remove everything from set #1 that doesn't have a date in set #2
dayInfos1.retainAll(dayInfos2);
// remove everything from set #2 that doesn't have a date in set #1
dayInfos2.retainAll(dayInfos1);
```

I think that would work.